# How do I set "Starting at : $12" value for a Grouped product in Magento? 

Tags: magento

I recently created a grouped product by going through a tutorial. Everything is working fine except for the fact that, in the front end, the text "Starting at : $0.00" is set to "$0.00" instead of the associated products' actual minimum price.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: This should work. Have you refreshed the price index?

Comment: Yes.. but still i am getting the same $0.00

Comment: What version of Magento?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.6.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Heh, the old `Starting At` bug.

Go to one of the individual product items in the group, increase its price by a penny, save and then reduce back to normal price.

This resets the group's `Starting At:` price.

No amount of reindexing will clear it and usually, it's only one or two Grouped items a month that will fail to update during a price change.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a forum post about this from the Magento forums](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/276346/):

User Lenster provides code for `app/design/frontend/[theme]/default/template/catalog/price.phtml` that shows the first price from the set of group items as the starting price.

```
<?php else: /* if (!$_product->isGrouped()): */ ?>
    <?php

    ?>
    <?php if ($this->getDisplayMinimalPrice() && $_minimalPriceValue): ?>
        <div class="price-box">
            <p class="minimal-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Starting at:') ?></span>
                <?php
                    $pos1_price = 0;
                    $specialprice = 0;
                    $products = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts();

                    foreach ($products as $product){
                        $prod_position = $product->getPosition();

                        if ($prod_position == 1):
                            $_exclTax = $product->getPrice();
                            $_inclTax = $product->getPrice();
                            $pos1_price = 1;
                               $specialprice = $product->getSpecialPrice();
                        endif;
                    }

                    if (!$pos1_price): 
                        $_exclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, $includingTax = null);
                        $_inclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, $includingTax = true);

                    endif;


                    if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
                        <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                            <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                                <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_exclTax, true, false) ?>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="price-including-tax">
                            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                            <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                                <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_inclTax, true, false) ?>
                            </span>
                            </span>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?php
                                $_showPrice = $_inclTax;
                                   if (!$_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax()) {
                                    $_showPrice = $_exclTax;
                                }


                                if ($specialprice): ?>

                                <span class="price">
                                <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($specialprice,true,false) ?>
                                </span>
                                <BR />
                                <p class="old-price">
                                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Was:') ?></span>

                                </span>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <span class="price" id="product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_showPrice, true, false) ?>
                                </span>
                        <?php endif; ?>

            </p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; /* if ($this->getDisplayMinimalPrice() && $_minimalPrice): */ ?>
<?php endif; /* if (!$_product->isGrouped()): */ ?>
```